# Trouble inserting data from csv into mysql database with unknown number of columns

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm having this very annoying problem for couple of days already, and I did research and everything, but it seems to be bigger than my programming skills and knowledge.

I have a situation where user can define custom columns in tables in my database, and now I need to import `CSV` files into that user's custom tables. Since I recently found out that tables need to be "dynamic" this is how I handled importing before:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    if (strrpos($name, '.csv', -4)) {//handling the csv file
                    do {
                        if ($data[0]) {
                            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `test` (`name`, `surname`, `email`) VALUES
                            (
                                '" . addslashes($data[0]) . "',
                                '" . addslashes($data[1]) . "',
                                '" . addslashes($data[2]) . "'
                            )
                        ");

                        }
                    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));
```

And that worked perfectly with static tables. But since I dont't know how many columns table will have, I tried something like this:

Building query method

```
 if (strrpos($name, '.csv', -4)) {//ubacije vrijednosti csv fajla u bazu
                do {
                    if ($data[0]) {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO $tabela (";
                        $last = end($anotherArray);
                        foreach ($anotherArray as $something) {//$anotherArray contains names of fields in user's custom table
                            if ($something != $last) {
                                $query .= "" . $something . ",";
                            } else {
                                $query .= "" . $something . ")";
                            }
                        }

                        $query .= "VALUES (";
                        foreach($data as $val){
                       $query .= "'$val',";
}


    }while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'"));

                $query=rtrim($query,',');
                $query.=")";
                //var_dump($query);
                $rez=$mysqli->query($query);
                //var_dump($rez);
```

But problem with this code is if csv file contains for example 2 or more colums like so:[image]

everything becomes part of that `VALUES` part of query. So query looks like this: `"INSERT INTO tabela12312334 (user_facebook_id,ime,prezime) VALUES('123123123','Ognjen','Babic','123123123','Neven',Babic)"` and of course number of fields isn't same as number of values.

Please help me to solve this, I'm desperate.

Comment: when you export as a csv you can edit csv setting and tick a box saying "quote all text cells". Thus all your row will have the same amount of column must it be empty

Comment: Yes. but I'm not really dealing with exporting csv.. I just need to import values from uploaded csv to my database..

Comment: If the number of columns can vary, you should require a header row that contains the column names. Then you can get all column names from the table and check for each column if there is a match.

Comment: What do you mean by header row? I already have number and names of columns in `$anotherArray` variable. Sorry if I misunderstood your advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'c:/path-to-csv-file/your-file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_awesome_table  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(field_1,field_2 , field_3);
```

***NB:*** the first row as the title  for your fields, you might have to include a header in your CSV file