# Inserting array which number of elements can vary into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, csv

I've found a bit of solution for my last question:[Trouble inserting data from csv into mysql database with unknown number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748971/trouble-inserting-data-from-csv-into-mysql-database-with-unknown-number-of-colum) , so let me explain whats my problem now. 
Since users of my app can make custom columns in tables of my database, I've found a way to store number and names of columns by running this query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name='$tblname'"
```

And I stored result in `$anotherArray` variable. Now, since my users have option to import `CSV` files into their custom tables(with custom number of columns) I did this:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
if (strrpos($name, '.csv', -4)) {//recognises if uploaded file is .csv
        do {
           if ($data[0]) {
                $query = "INSERT INTO $tabela (";
                $last = end($anotherArray);//$anotherArray holds names and number of columns user have made
                foreach ($anotherArray as $something) {
                    if ($something != $last) {
                        $query .= "" . $something . ",";
                        } else {
                            $query .= "" . $something . ")";
                            }
                        }

            $query .= "VALUES (";
```

So since the uploaded csv file will look something like this: [image]

Please note again that this is a testing file, and some user will maybe make 9 custom columns in his table and his document will have 9 values within one row of csv file.
I made this part of script to make an array out of values of that csv:

```
$lengtara = count($anotherArray);

                $length1 = count($data);//$data is array with csv file values
                $nizDuzina = count($anotherArray);
                $restructured1 = [];
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length1; $i += $nizDuzina) { // note the $i+=$nizDuzina increments $i by number of columns in database table.
                for ($j = 0; $j < $nizDuzina; $j++) {
                $restructed1 [$j] = $data[$i + $j];//this is a key thing in my script!
                    }
        }
        }
        }
                while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",", "'")) ;
$query = rtrim($query, ',');
                $query .= ")";
                //var_dump($query);
                $rez = $mysqli->query($query);
```

So when I do `print_r($restructed1)` I get an array like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 123123123 [1] => Ognjen [2] => Babic ) Array ( [0] => 23423423 [1] => Neven [2] => Babic ) Array ( [0] => 235646345 [1] => Vanja [2] => Babic ) Array ( [0] => 4853424 [1] => Nikola [2] => Babic ) Array ( [0] => 34545747 [1] => Viktor [2] => Sovilj )
```

**NOW** this is a key point of my question: How to import array like this into a database, but in some dynamic, general way, so it can suit for exaple if arrays within my array has 2 or 7 elements both?